# Output of Python loop not going to text file

Tags: python

```
from collections import Counter
from glob import iglob

import re
import os

def remove_garbage(text):
    """Replace non-word (non-alphanumeric) chars in text with spaces,
       then convert and return a lowercase version of the result.
    """
    text = re.sub(r'\W+', ' ', text)
    text = text.lower()
    return text

topwords = 50000
folderpath = 'd:/jktextall/'
counter = Counter()

for filepath in iglob(os.path.join(folderpath, '*.txt')):
    with open(filepath) as file:
        counter.update(remove_garbage(file.read()).split())
file1 = open("jkwords1.txt","w")
for word, count in counter.most_common(topwords):
file1.write (str(count) +"," + word + "\n")

file1.close
```

I have modified the code above to write the output to a text file `jkwords1.txt`. Nothing is being written to the text file. However, `print (word,count)` does produce an output in the python console.

However, instead of the `file1.write`, if `print(count,word)` is used, it results in a screen output.

Comment: Use `with open(...) as file1: ...` to make sure everything gets written to disk properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not calling the `close` function properly.

`file1.close` -> `file1.close()`

Comment: Did that. Only one record is in the jkwords1.txt file as against none earlier (before using file1.close()). However, the print keyword results in a large output.

Comment: Do you mind fixing the indentation in the question, `file1.write (str(count) +"," + word + "\n")` doesn't seem to be indented correctly.

Comment: Thanks. The change of indentation helped. Am new to Python. Need to learn more.